# Conditionally set value of key in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a method that returns a hash of parsed values. Some of the values in the hash I want to be `nil` if a condition is met, but I'm unable to write a conditional in the value.

Is there a way I can conditionally set the value of a key without having a bunch of `if`/`else` statements outside of the hash?

See `asignee_handle:` and `issue_closed_at:` below:

```
def parse(issue)
    {
      github_id:          issue['id'].to_i,
      github_number:      issue['number'].to_i,
      github_url:         issue['url'],
      title:              issue['title'],
      body:               issue['body'],
      creator_handle:     issue['user']['login'],
      asignee_handle:     issue['assignee']['login'] if issue['assignee'] #can't do this,
      asignee_avatar_url: issue['assignee']['avatar_url'],
      issue_created_at:   issue['created_at'].to_datetime,
      issue_updated_at:   issue['updated_at'].to_datetime,
      issue_closed_at:    issue['closed_at'].to_datetime if issue['closed_at'],
      repo:               issue['url'].split('/')[5]
    }
  end
```

Comment: `asignee_handle:   issue['assignee'] ? issue['assignee']['login'] : nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some brackets around the values:

```
def parse(issue)
  {
    #...
    asignee_handle: (issue['assignee']['login'] if issue['assignee']),
    #...
  }
end
```

The value of the `:asignee_handle` key will now either be `issue['assignee']['login']` or it will be `nil` (or you will get an error if `issue['assignee']` isn’t a hash).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following conditional assignment using `if` statement:

```
asignee_handle: if issue['assignee'] then issue['assignee']['login'] end
```

or use a ternary operator `[expression] ? [true] : [false]`:

```
asignee_handle: issue['assignee'] ? issue['assignee']['login'] : nil
```